# How to recognize very close complex numbers as equal?

Tags: python, numpy, complex-numbers

I'm using numerical method to find the cube root of 1. My method works, i.e. converging at the three roots from different starting point, judging by eyes.

However, when I use `numpy.unique()` to get the three roots, the slightly different complex part prevents me from extracting the roots.

Right now I'm separating each complex number into real and imaginary part, round the parts and compare. However, that is quite clunky. Is there a better way?

Comment: You should include the code you are using to do the rounding and comparing on those complex numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would calculate the absolute value of their difference and compare to float's epsilon:

```
import math
import sys


def almost_equal(a, b):
    d = a - b
    return math.sqrt(d.real ** 2 + d.imag ** 2) < sys.float_info.epsilon
```

Comment: Doesn't this get into problems if two complex numbers have the same parts, only with opposite signs? When squared, the different signs become the same.

Comment: But then these complex numbers are the negative of each other and no equal. I guess I'm missing something.

Comment: That computes the euclidean distance between the complex numbers which is a proper metric space.